# Jquery onmouseover image size increase

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I am trying to do an effect where when the mouse hovers over an image the it grows large by 50% of its size and goes back as soon as the mouse moves out of its region. Can it be possible to do this with jquery? how? could it be possible to do this without jquery? how hard would it be to do it without jquery?

Comment: How hard would it be without jQuery? **Unnecessary** hard.

Comment: In my example below, you will probably think there isn't much difference. But what about if you want to get an image using a different selector (i.e. not the ID), and then what about if you want to animate the transition (jQuery does this with ease). And also, with jQuery, you don't have to worry about cross-browser compatibility to anywhere near the same extent.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$('img').load(function() {
    $(this).data('height', this.height);
}).bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        height: $(this).data('height') * (e.type === 'mouseenter' ? 1.5 : 1)
    });
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/fwUMx/5/

Comment: would it work if the images were inside a table with fixed width

Comment: Thanks a lot, its is brilliant. http://jsfiddle.net/fwUMx/6/. Could it be possible that the table does not move when the mouse moves over the image.

Comment: @user I've been able to achieve a decent effect by explicitly setting the height of the table cell. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/fwUMx/10/

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using pure CSS. Here is a [running sample](http://jsfiddle.net/kEhxk/).

Given this HTML:

```
<img class="foo" src="/img/logo.png">
```

Add this CSS:

```
body { background-color: black }
.foo {
    height:25px;
}
.foo:hover {
    height:50px;
}
```

Use jQuery if one of your target browser doesn't support decent CSS, but I tested in IE8, and it supports this.

Comment: You are hard-coding the height values into the CSS. What if the images have different dimensions?

Comment: You'd have to do a per-image css style. If you have _lots_ of images, this would be a good place to use jquery instead.

Comment: Good idea :) i would like to upvote your answer but dont have enough rep.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this with jQuery, which is a **JavaScript** *library*, et alors: you can also use plain JavaScript.

jQuery:

```
var $image = $('#imageID'), //Or some other selector
    imgWidth = $image.width(),
    imgHeight = $image.height();
$('#imageID').hover(function() {
  //The mouseover 
  $(this).width( imgWidth * 2);
  $(this).height( imgHeight * 2);      
}, function() {
  $(this).width( imgWidth );
  $(this).height( imgHeight );
});
```

**Plain JavaScript:**
See Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/axpVw/

```
var image = document.getElementById('imageID'),
    imageWidth = image.width,
    imageHeight = image.height;
image.onmouseover = function() {
  image.width = 2 * imageWidth;
  image.height = 2 * imageHeight;
}
image.onmouseout = function() {
  image.width = imageWidth;
  image.height = imageHeight;
}
```

Comment: @Šime Vidas has given a cleaner example for the jQuery - really would recommend animating properties.

Answer (score 1):

It is a easy task in both the ways. I have fiddles for you with an example in both the ways:

1. **Jquery**: http://jsfiddle.net/G7yTU/

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){      
   var ht= $("img").height(),      
   wd=$("img").width(),      
   mult=1.5; //change to the no. of times you want to increase your image 
         //size.
   $("img").on('mouseenter', function(){
   $(this).animate({height: ht*mult,
                    width: wd*mult}, 500);
   });
   $("img").on('mouseleave', function(){
   $(this).animate({height: ht,
                    width: wd}, 500);
   })
   });
   ```
2. **CSS**: http://jsfiddle.net/zahAB/1/

   ```
   img{
   -webkit-transition:all 0.5s;
   -moz-transition:all 0.5s;
   -ms-transition:all 0.5s;
   -o-transition:all 0.5s;
      }

   img:hover{
       width:150px;
       height:150px;
   }
   ```

If you need any help, please contact.

Comment: Which method is better?

Comment: I would say use Jquery because it will be globally supported plus it can be easily edited according to your needs. ex. if you want the image to expand by 300% just change the variable to 3 and your job is done.