# Issue with jQuery onmouseover browser compatability

Tags: jquery

I got this example from a previous StackOverflow question [Jquery onmouseover image size increase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357724/jquery-onmouseover-image-size-increase)

Here is a link to an example of mouseover: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/fwUMx/5/

The above example works in Chrome but not in Firefox or IE.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Works for me in Firefox 4 on Ubuntu 11.04. I don't have access to Windows, currently, so I can't say what the problem is or might be.

Comment: @BrunoLM: thanks :) I don't know if the OS matters, but it seems to (if FF4 on Win XP is problematic, though on Win 7 works).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Forcing image load events

Check out my reply on this thread: [jQuery - Complete loading animation on each individual image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796273/jquery-complete-loading-animation-on-each-individual-image/5796429#5796429)

As it is mentioned on the jQuery documentation page for the load event, there are some issues with it. On IE, it doesn't always fire the first time and on webkit browsers it doesn't always fire if it's read from the cache.

You're using the `load()` event to save the images original height to a data attribute, but due to the above it's not always set, so the resizing doesn't work.

The solution is to put the following little piece of code into your ready function, which clears and resets the `src` attribute on all images (or change it to certain images if you like) to force the firing of the load event.

```
$('img').each(function(){
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).attr('src','#');
    $(this).attr('src',src);
});
```

Here is your fixed jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fwUMx/86/

### Automatically cycle through images

If you want to have the same effect to automatically cycle through images, you just need to write a few extra functions and call them in the animation complete callback. Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fwUMx/99/

```
var images = null;
var animation_speed = 500;
var wait = 1500;

function ZoomIn(element){
    element.animate({
        height: element.data('height') * 1.5
    }, animation_speed, function(){
        // Zoom in animation ended, schedule next image
        setTimeout(function(){
            ZoomOut(element);
        }, wait);
        setTimeout(function(){
            var next = element.next();

            // Comment out the next line if you don't want the animation to restart after last image.
            if(element.index() == images.length - 1) next = images.eq(0);

            ZoomIn(next);
        }, wait);
    });
}

function ZoomOut(element){
    element.animate({
        height: element.data('height') * 1
    }, animation_speed);
}

function StartAnimation(){
    // Make sure images object is set
    if(!images) return;

    ZoomIn(images.eq(0));
}

$(function(){
    images = $('img');

    var cnt = images.length;
    var loaded = 0;

    images.load(function() {
        $(this).data('height', this.height);
        loaded++;

        // Start the animation after all images have loaded
        if(loaded == cnt) StartAnimation();
    });

    // Force image load events
    images.each(function(){
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src','#');
        $(this).attr('src',src);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. it works great. also is it possible to loop through the list of images, and highlight them for few seconds and when second image is about to highlight the previous image should be dehighlighted. I mean can this be done automatically on page load without mouseover?

Comment: @user508518 - I have edited the post, added automatic cycling through the images, is this what you had in mind?